# Pull container image from Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-lightsail

Is there a way to pull Lightsail container images once they are pushed there?

The `get-container-images` CLI only returns a list of the images but you can't actually pull them.

We have lost the `Dockerfile` that built the original image but the image is in Lightsail so would like to retrieve the image.